# facing issues while Displaying Json data in to dynamic tabs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp

I am trying following code to display the tabs and tab content from Json data dynamically

```
<script>
var area, cus, project, curst;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./QuizServlet",
success: function(responseText) {
    console.log("rs" + responseText.toString());
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseText);
    var questions = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        area = jsonData[i].area;
        console.log("area" + area);
        project = jsonData[i].projectName;
        console.log("poj" + project);
        projectdes = jsonData[i].projectDescription;
        console.log("pojdes" + projectdes);
        curst = jsonData[i].currentStatus;
        console.log("cus" + curst);
        var test = {
            area: area,
            cus: curst,
            project: project,
            projectdes: projectdes,
        }
        questions.push(test);
        console.log("output" + test);
        alert(JSON.stringify(test));

    }
}
});

 for (var i in test) {
 $('.nav-tabs').append('<li role="area" class=""><a href="#' + i + '"       aria-controls="' + i + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + i + '</a></li>');

var div = '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" area="' + i + '">';

for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    var obj = data[i][j];

    div += '<div area="' + obj.project + '">' + obj.projectdes + '</div>';
 }

$('.tab-content').append(div);
}

$('.nav-tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');
$('.tab-content div').eq(0).addClass('active');
</script>



<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"></ul>
<div class="tab-content"></div>
</div>
 </body>
```

My Json data is coming correctly in JSON format from DB: Below data is coming fine from DB . I printed using alert statement

```
 {"area":"CSE","cus":"progress","project":"Project 1","projectdes":"Class    1st"}
{"area":"ECE","cus":"complered","project":"Project 2","projectdes":"This is class 1st Project"}
{"area":"IT","cus":"progress","project":"project 1","projectdes":"This is Class 2nd project"}
{"area":"IT","cus":"pending","project":"Project 2","projectdes":"This is class 2nd project"}
```

I am trying to display area in tabs and other fields in tab content.But
the data is not getting displayed in jsp. I tried so many ways.But still data is not getting in tabs and tabs content. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Where is your JSP code?

Comment: @Manoj, the <script> and <body > code i have mentioned in jsp code (code already attached in first)But this tab and content content not showing in jsp..Please help me .

Comment: Sorry Rahul, My bad. !! I couldn't see that part at first look. Thanks.!!

Comment: @ManojShukla , now you are able to see..right? I am thinking the javascript code i have written to create tabs and tab content might be not correct..could you please correct me

Comment: @ManojShukla, yeah I got it. Can you please help me to resolve this issue. or suggest me other way to dispaly data in to tabs using tabs. I would be very thankful to you

Comment: @ManojShukla, i want to display Area like CSE, ECE and IT in tabs. the other fields like project and projectdes in tab content

Comment: sorry rahul, your requirement is unclear, also your code contains unnecessary lines. Please clear it in detail.

Comment: @ManojShukla, please tell me which code is unclear. so that i can clear it detail

Comment: why there is two dimensional array iteration? `for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                            var obj = data[i][j];

                            div += '<div area="' + obj.project + '">' + obj.projectdes + '</div>';
                        }`

Comment: yeah...i thought to do to display tab content(j) based on tab(i). If you think this is not right code. Can you please suggest me some other javascript so that tabs and tab content can be generated

Comment: Also, what if there are two projects with same area, I man, do you want to merge the descriptions it in a single tab of that area, you you need repeated tabs for each duplicate area??

Comment: yes @ManojShukla, i want to merge the descriptions it in a single tab of that area. I do not want  repeated tabs for each duplicate area. But want to merge the descriptions it in a single tab of that area

Comment: Fine Rahul, now I can think in that way.. 

Comment: @ManojShukla, can you please help me with working code soon. so that i can learn from you the concepts and apply in future also

Comment: Yes Rahul, I'm working on it. It's not a cup of tea man.. I've to test the code after completion to make sure that it works and it doesn't confuse you and other users on SO community. Have patients dear. & thanks for accepting the answer, but I'll update it, as it is not the exact solution you are looking for.

Comment: @ManojShukla, Actually i was trying from 2 days..my issue is not getting resolved. So, I am excited to see working one. As you are expert. so yiu can guide me and help me.:)

Comment: No Dear, I don't mind..!! Just Chill.. !! I can understand the level of excitement. And I'm not an expert. I'm just a naive like others.

Comment: I'm stuck at a point, with HTML and CSS.. but the code is working fine.. Is it ohk If I modify the structure of html ??

Comment: yes , you can modify it...

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/gASYjkqOAJepFdy4XEfv?p=preview see this plunkr code then.., if you have any doubt, ask me right there..!!

Comment: is it something you are looking for. ?

Comment: yeah..i am looking like this only. But I want to display tabs in horizontal way

Comment: That's part of bootstrap or other UI frameworks your code uses.. You can change the DOM modification part according to your needs.

Comment: ok...i will implement your code and test it .Thank you so much MAnoj..i will stuck somewhere i will ask you.:)

Comment: @Manoj, it is really helpful . with static data, it is coming output as expected. with dynamic data , i am getting some errors. But your logic is correct. May be i need some changes. I tried to up vote. As i have less then 15 votes,,.it is not displaying publically..:( But it is recorded ..Thank you so much Bro...can i share your email id if possible. I want to ask 1-2 errors coming in console as a pert of dynamic data..or i can ask here only?

Comment: @ManojShukla, I am getting the error ReferenceError: showData is not defined[Learn More] while displaying dynamic data. When i am displaying data using static data, this error is not coming. Could you please help to resolve this error. Because of this error, output is not coming..Already i am really very very thanks to you..please help me for this issue also

Comment: And about your error, remove `onLoad="showData()"` form body tag, please refer the updated answer's script if needed.

Comment: Thank you Manoj. I have refer the updated answers' script. Now, tabs are coming from DB. But tab content is showing undefined

Comment: post a new question on that, as it would help you to gain more SO points which is helpful for longer discussions, we can move the discussion to chat room, once you have enough points, so ask a new question and it would help others too.. Is it OK?

Comment: I corrected the table columns name. Now, output is coming one question, you can see , projectname is not coming in all tabs. But we have defined the project column . Only ProjectDes is not coming not project data.

Comment: Sorry Rahul I did't get you. Where did you correct the table? what columns you are talking about?

Comment: As you can see , we are fetching responseText[j].project. For eg: in static code,  var responseText = [{
        "area": "CSE",
        "cus": "progress",
        "project": "Project 1",
        "projectdes": "Class    1st"    } we are fetching this projet. but project data is not coming in output. Manoj you got me?

Comment: Does it show the `projectdes`??

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/gASYjkqOAJepFdy4XEfv?p=preview see this plunkr code, it is showing here !!

Comment: it should show project and projectdes both. But now it is showing only projectdes.As you can see in below your working link

Comment: Did you see updated plunkr ???

Comment: yeah now it is showing..did you change some code?

Comment: Yup, see this line, `'Project Description is:' + obj.project + '<br>Project is:' +  obj.projectdes `

Comment: Asking a new question will not notify me, but it will be available to so many great people available on the Universe. If you want me to be notified, you may leave a comment here after posing your question, as the comments posted here will automatically notify me whenever I'm online. :) Glad to hep you. :) Keep Learning !! Keep Sharing !!

Comment: Thanks for the complement rahul !! But I would advice, ask a new question, and if you want my attention, post a comment here, with the link of new question, there are other ppl who are much much better than me, they'll surely help you, and you also can increase your privileges to access the community even better. And, I can also react once you leave the comment here. !! :)

Comment: @ManojShukla, HI Manoj. I am facing some issue. I am able to display bootstrap tabs. But all tab content is coming on page display, I am doing using dynamic data. BUt in the question, i have mentioned static data. an you please help me on this also. . The questin url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139346/all-tab-content-is-coming-on-page-load-i-want-only-active-tab-data-to-be-displa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the answer, you can replace the part of your `<script>` tag by the code below. And to make the UI feel better, modify the HTML and DOM part as per the UI frameworks like bootstrap, etc.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./QuizServlet",
        success: function (responseText) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var uniueTabs = getUniqueLists(jsonData);
            for (var i = 0; i < uniueTabs.length; i++) {
                $('.nav-tabs').append('<li role="area" class="my-li' + i + '"><a href="#' + i +
                    '"       aria-controls="' + i + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + uniueTabs[i].area +
                    '</a></li>');

                var div = '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" area="' + i + '">';

                for (var j = 0; j < uniueTabs[i].tabContent.length; j++) {
                    var obj = uniueTabs[i].tabContent[j];

                    div += '<div area="' + obj.project + '">' + obj.projectdes + '</div>';
                }

                $('.my-li' + i).append(div);
            }

            $('.nav-tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');
            $('.tab-content div').eq(0).addClass('active');

        }
    });

    function getUniqueLists(responseText) {
        var resArr = [];
        responseText.filter(function (x, i) {
            if (resArr.indexOf(x.area) === -1) {
                resArr.push(x.area);
            }
        })
        //console.log(resArr);
        return mergeDataAreaWise(resArr, responseText);
    }

    function mergeDataAreaWise(area, responseText) {
        var tabList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < area.length; i++) {
            tabList.push({
                area: area[i],
                tabContent: []
            });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < responseText.length; j++) {
                var Obj = {
                    cus: responseText[j].cus,
                    project: responseText[j].project,
                    projectdes: responseText[j].projectdes
                }
                var currentArea = responseText[j].area;
                if (tabList[i].area === currentArea) {
                    tabList[i].tabContent.push(Obj);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(tabList);
        return tabList;
    }
</script>
```

[Here is a similar plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gASYjkqOAJepFdy4XEfv?p=preview)

Comment: ,can you please correct my code.I am trying from 3-4 days..but no t able to resolve it