# All tab content is coming on page load. I want only active tab data to be displayed

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I am using below code to display the json data into tabs using javascript. I am able to display the data in UI. But it is not coming proper tab format. Tab click also not working. Could you please help me to resolve my issue. Below is my code:

```
<script>
var responseText = [{
    "area": "CSE",
    "cus": "progress",
    "project": "Project 1",
    "projectdes": "Class    1st"
}, {
    "area": "ECE",
    "cus": "complered",
    "project": "Project 2",
    "projectdes": "This is class 1st Project"
}, {
    "area": "IT",
    "cus": "progress",
    "project": "project 1",
    "projectdes": "This is Class 2nd project"
}, {
    "area": "IT",
    "cus": "pending",
    "project": "Project 2",
    "projectdes": "This is class 2nd project"
}];
function showData() {
    var uniueTabs = getUniqueLists(responseText);


    for (var i = 0; i < uniueTabs.length; i++) {
        $(#tabs).append('<li role="area" class="my-li'+i+'"><a href="#' + i +
            '"       aria-controls="' + i + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + uniueTabs[i].area +
            '</a></li>');

        var div = '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" area="' + i + '">';

        for (var j = 0; j < uniueTabs[i].tabContent.length; j++) {
            var obj = uniueTabs[i].tabContent[j];

            div += '<div area="' + obj.project + '">' + obj.projectdes + '</div>';
        }

        $('.my-li'+i).append(div);
    }

    $('#tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');
    $('#tab-content div').eq(0).addClass('active');

}

function getUniqueLists(responseText) {
    var resArr = [];
    responseText.filter(function (x, i) {
        if (resArr.indexOf(x.area) === -1) {
            resArr.push(x.area);
        }
    })
    //console.log(resArr);
    return mergeDataAreaWise(resArr, responseText);
}

function mergeDataAreaWise(area, responseText) {
    var tabList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < area.length; i++) {
        tabList.push({
            area: area[i],
            tabContent: []
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < responseText.length; j++) {
            var Obj = {
                cus: responseText[j].cus,
                project: responseText[j].project,
                projectdes: responseText[j].projectdes
            }
            var currentArea = responseText[j].area;
            if (tabList[i].area === currentArea) {
                tabList[i].tabContent.push(Obj);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(tabList);
    return tabList;
}
 </script>      
 <body onload="showData()">
 <div id="tabs" role="tablist">    
 <div id="tab-content">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
#tabs {
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#tabs li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}
#tabs a {
box-shadow: -4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
background: #ad1c1c;
background: linear-gradient(220deg, transparent 10px, #ad1c1c 10px);
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
color: #fff;
float: left;
font: bold 12px/35px 'Lucida sans', Arial, Helvetica;
height: 35px;
padding: 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#tabs a:hover {
background: #c93434;
background: linear-gradient(220deg, transparent 10px, #c93434 10px);     
}
#tabs a:focus {
outline: 0;
 }
#tabs #current a {
background: #fff;
background: linear-gradient(220deg, transparent 10px, #fff 10px);
text-shadow: none;    
color: #333;
}
#content {
background-color: #fff;
background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 2px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000, 0 -1px 0 #fff inset;
padding: 30px;
}
#content div {
height: 220px; 
}
```

The UI ouput is coming as shown in url :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwQS1.jpg)

I am facing problem while displaying tab content in proper format and tab click not working. Please help me to resolve my issue

Comment: are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: one thing i noticed - its not a good idea to mix initialization methods.  you may have a race condition between body onload=showData() and the jquery snippet.  also it doesn't look like your var div has a close div.

Comment: i didn't post an answer with working code because i don't have time to do that much right now.  did you try closing the div?  did you try using the inspector to see if the DOM is turning out like you want?  that's where i'd start

Comment: @xeo, i have checked div is closed and i am trying also to resolve the issue. But still same type of output coming. Once free, please help me correct my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plnkr demo will do the job, http://plnkr.co/edit/xlLwsoSlCzk4qsG3ZMKH?p=preview

And, here is the code with static data, you can make changes accordingly to perform ajax call for dynamic data.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var responseText = [{
        "area": "CSE",
        "cus": "progress",
        "project": "Project 1",
        "projectdes": "Class    1st"
    }, {
        "area": "ECE",
        "cus": "complered",
        "project": "Project 2",
        "projectdes": "This is class 1st Project"
    }, {
        "area": "IT",
        "cus": "progress",
        "project": "project 1",
        "projectdes": "This is Class 2nd project"
    }, {
        "area": "IT",
        "cus": "pending",
        "project": "Project 2",
        "projectdes": "This is class 2nd project"
    }];

    function showData() {
        var uniueTabs = getUniqueLists(responseText);

        for (var i = 0; i < uniueTabs.length; i++) {
            $('.nav-tabs').append('<li ><a href="#tab-content-' + i + '">' + uniueTabs[i].area + '</a></li>');
            var div = '<div id="tab-content-' + i + '" class="tab-pane fade">';

            for (var j = 0; j < uniueTabs[i].tabContent.length; j++) {
                var obj = uniueTabs[i].tabContent[j];
                div += '<p>' + obj.projectdes + '</p>';
            }

            $('.tab-content').append(div);
            $('#tab-content-0').addClass('in active');
        }

        $('.nav-tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');
        setListner();

    }

    function getUniqueLists(responseText) {
        var resArr = [];
        responseText.filter(function (x, i) {
            if (resArr.indexOf(x.area) === -1) {
                resArr.push(x.area);
            }
        })
        return mergeDataAreaWise(resArr, responseText);
    }

    function mergeDataAreaWise(area, responseText) {
        var tabList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < area.length; i++) {
            tabList.push({
                area: area[i],
                tabContent: []
            });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < responseText.length; j++) {
                var Obj = {
                    cus: responseText[j].cus,
                    project: responseText[j].project,
                    projectdes: responseText[j].projectdes
                }
                var currentArea = responseText[j].area;
                if (tabList[i].area === currentArea) {
                    tabList[i].tabContent.push(Obj);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(tabList);
        return tabList;
    }
    function setListner () {
        $(".nav-tabs a").click(function () {
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    }
</script>

<body onload="showData()">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: HI Manoj, this is what i want. Thank you so much. Now, I am doing for dynamic data.

Comment: HI Manoj, I am able to display data according to tab, But tab content is coming undefined.

Comment: Now, tab content is coming. The column name was wrong in my side

Comment: Now, it is working. Now, i am fetching all the columns data..If i will facs any issues. can i ask you

Comment: Actually in column: ProjectDes and Cus column, I am using pipe symbol(|)  to split the data and display in next line. Before i was using var= projectdes.split("|") to split the data in jsp. Now as you can see, we are fetching data from JSON.where i can define var= projectdes.split("|") in jsp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162744/discussion-between-manoj-shukla-and-rahul).

Comment: HI Manoj, once you get time..can you please help me to resolve the issuea as i have shared in github

Comment: See in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162744/discussion-between-manoj-shukla-and-rahul

Comment: HI Manoj, I need one your one more help...could you please help me. I amnot able to return the list in json Array. Can you please help me.I have posted this question : I am not able to fetch the list value in Servlet using JsonArray . i am not able to get any response